# Apple installer command help for bash script

Tags: bash, terminal, installation

I am trying to use the Apple Installer commands to install a package and the output is that it was successful, however, the end result is that nothing actually happens meaning the package never gets installed or launched. Could someone please look over the commands and tell me what is wrong or try it themselves to see what could be the issue?

```
#Machines must have cURL installed as a prerequisite to download software from internet or FTP server 

#grab files from www.teamviewer.com or custom FTP server
curl -O http://download.teamviewer.com/download/TeamViewerHost.dmg

#Mount and Install TeamViewer
hdiutil mount /Users/TeamViewer/Downloads/TeamViewerHost.dmg
sudo cp -R "/Volumes/TeamViewerHost" /Applications

#Run installer
sudo installer -package /Applications/TeamViewerHost/Install\ TeamViewerHost.pkg -target "/Volumes/TeamViewerHost"

#Unmount package
cd ~
hdiutil unmount "/Volumes/TeamViewerHost/"
```

Or what else I have tried is this with the same result:

```
#Machines must have cURL installed as a prerequisite to download software from internet or FTP server 

#grab files from www.teamviewer.com or custom FTP server
curl -O http://download.teamviewer.com/download/TeamViewerHost.dmg

#Mount and Install TeamViewer
hdiutil mount /Users/TeamViewer/Downloads/TeamViewerHost.dmg

#Run installer
sudo installer -package /Volumes/TeamViewerHost/Install\ TeamViewerHost.pkg -target "/Volumes/TeamViewerHost"

#Unmount package
cd ~
hdiutil unmount "/Volumes/TeamViewerHost/"
```

The need is to install TeamViewer over SSH through terminal, but Installer is not playing nice. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general computing issues not related to programming within the scope defined in the [help]. You may be able to get help on [apple.se] or [su].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run:

```
sudo installer -pkg /Volumes/TeamViewerHost/Install\ TeamViewerHost.pkg -target /
```

The `-target /` mean - where the the "root" for the installing package.

When you said `-target "/Volumes/TeamViewerHost"` it tries install into the mounted `.dmg` what is read-only and not what you want.

*Ps: better to ask on apple.stackexchange.*

## EDIT:

Just tried the next:

```
ssh me@myanothercomp.local
cd Downloads
curl -O http://downloadeu1.teamviewer.com/download/TeamViewerHost.dmg
hdutil mount TeamViewerHost.dmg
sudo installer -pkg /Volumes/TeamViewerHost/Install\ TeamViewerHost.pkg -target /
```

the sudo/installer prints:

```
Password:
installer: Package name is TeamViewerHost
installer: Installing at base path /
installer: The install was successful.
```

and got installed the `TeamViewerHost.app` into the `/Applications` on the remote Mac.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Didnt know they had an Apple stackexchange and maybe this will get moved.

Comment: Okay so I have tried both ways into the root and the volume. The reason why I chose the volume was because when I try -target /Users/User/Applications I get an error that says Installer: error trying to locate volume. And this is the same error that I keep getting for any target path besides the Volume path where it says successful. Plus I figured that if I am able to double-click on the package through the mounted drive through the GUI it works too just not through the terminal. Any other suggestions

Comment: I got it and thanks for the help! When you said root instead of thinking of just / I was misplacing it. It works

Comment: Thank you Nemo for the comment. I went ahead and accepted the answer and read the link provided. I had moved this topic over to apple stack exchange and received the answers in more depth at hxxp://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142668/shell-script-help